# restatables and \listoftheorem

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, thmtools

I am using the `restatable` environment from the `thm-restate` package of`thmtools`.

I am also using `\listoftheorems` command to give me a list of the theorems.

However, my restatable theorem is appearing twice in the list of theorems, even when I used the starred version.
My feeling is that it should only be in the list of theorems once.

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{thm}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={thm}]

\section{First}

\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\end{restatable}

\begin{thm}
Some other theorem
\end{thm}

Lets look at the first one again
\goldbach*

\end{document}
```

I've tried using the `ignoreall` key and to show just `thm` environments, but I guess the restatable is a `thm` too so this doesn't work.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I got around this by not using restatable and by creating a new un-numbered theorem environment.

Answer (score 5):

This solution requires some customisation of the `thmtools` files.

Copy the file `thm-listof.sty` into the same directory as your document and alter it; I was doing this anyway in order to reformat the list of theorems. If you try to override the format in your preamble, it does not work due to the packages use of `\AtBeginDocument`.

In this file, find the block which starts `\addtotheorempostheadhook{%` and modify it to read:

```
\newif\ifdontputthminlist
\dontputthminlistfalse
\addtotheorempostheadhook{%
  \ifdontputthminlist\else
  \thmtlo@chaptervspacehack
  \addcontentsline{loe}{\thmt@envname}{%
    \csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname
  }%
  \fi
}
```

Then, when you restate your theorem with `\oldtheorem*` just write it as follows:

```
\dontputthminlisttrue
\oldtheorem*
\dontputthminlistfalse
```

This may also come in handy if there's some random theorem you don't want to show up in the list for any other reason.
If you want, you could adopt this approach but flip the flag automatically by modifying the code in `thm-restate.sty`, but I haven't tried that since this sufficed.

Comment: When I try to modify the `addtotheorempostheadhook` block as you say, I get the error `(./thm-listof.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.122 \dontputhminlistfalse`.

Comment: @ImmanuelWeihnachten There was a typo in the code... The command should be `\dontputthminlistfalse` with two `t`'s.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: The first, simpler option is to write additional code into the `*.loe` file (which is where the list of theorems is stored) to prevent the superfluous lines to be printed. This can simply be achieved like this:

```
\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\iffalse}
\goldbach*
\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\fi}
```

All theorems between the two `\addtocontents` commands will be omitted from the list of theorems.

The other option would be to prevent the restated theorems from writing the additional `\contentsline`s to the `*.loe` file in the first place. However, this is likely to be more complicated, as the `thm-listof.sty` package uses `\addtotheorempostheadhook` to make theorems automatically write to the `*.loe` file, and this command is already executed when you load the package. It should be possible to locally redefine `\addcontentsline`, which is used inside the hook, to be a no-op.

Comment: If i try this
```\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\iffalse}
\goldbach*
\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\fi}```
 i get the error message:
```! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.```